# require.js loading bootstrap undefined

Tags: backbone.js, twitter-bootstrap, requirejs, amd

My main.js look as below

```
requirejs.config({
//By default load any module IDs from ../js
baseUrl: '../js',
paths : {
    'jquery': 'libs/jquery',
    'underscore': 'libs/underscore',
    'backbone': 'libs/backbone',
    'bootstrap': 'libs/bootstrap'
},
shim: {
    'jquery': {
        exports: '$'
    },
    'backbone': {
        //These script dependencies should be loaded before loading
        //backbone.js
        deps: ['jquery', 'underscore'],
        //Once loaded, use the global 'Backbone' as the
        //module value.
        exports: 'Backbone'
    },
    'underscore': {
        exports: '_'
    },
    'bootstrap': {
        deps: ['jquery'],
        exports: 'Bootstrap'
    }
}
});
define(
    ['jquery', 'backbone','underscore', 'bootstrap'],

    function (j, b,  u, boot) {
        console.log('jquery', j);
        console.log('backbone', b);
        console.log('underscore',u);
        console.log('bootstrap', boot);
    }
);
```

And my console image is like this:

[image]

When I click on X sign in alert, they disappear. So, I think bootstrap.js is loaded correctly. However, it says undefined in console. Can anyone make me clear is the bootstrap.js is loaded correctly and safe to use? And why it is saying undefined while rest of are defined well in console.

Comment: May be because all `jquery`, `backbone` and `underscore` create (export) globals, while `bootstrap` will just add plugins to the existing `jquery` object and won't export anything globally, hence won't receive anything in the define callback.

Comment: @Cyclone, so, technically i dont have problem the bootstrap library later.

Comment: Yes, if you've used any bootstrap thing on the page, and if its working, you should not have :)

Answer (score 3):

As `jquery`, `backbone`, and `underscore` export global variables to be used elsewhere, while `bootstrap` will just take the `existing jquery object` and will add plugins to the object, hence it won't export anything.

So, if you try to receive it in `define` callback, ideally it will be `undefined`. If you've used any `bootstrap component` on the page and if it is working it means bootstrap is integrated.

From the requirejs [shim docs](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim)

> For "modules" that are just jQuery or Backbone plugins that do not need to export any module value, the shim config can just be an array of dependencies:
>
> ```
> requirejs.config({
>   shim: {
>     'bootstrap': ['jquery']
>   }
> });
> ```

So, if you want, you can declare bootstrap like its specified in the docs.